# What does getTextContent() and item(0) return in Java DOM API?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Please explain the meaning of the following line of the code which is used in reading XML file using java.

```
NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
long     NameElement  = (long)lastNameList.item(0).getTextContent();
```

What is the use of `getTextContent()` and what is `item(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
```

finds all the descendant elements (children, grandchildren, etc.) under `firstPersonElement` that are named `last`, and returns them as a `NodeList` in document order.

```
lastNameList.item(0)
```

will be the first element from that list (think of it as an array index, so `item(0)` is the first node in the list, `item(1)` is the second, etc.).  And

```
lastNameList.item(0).getTextContent()
```

will be a *String* (not a `long`) value containing the concatenation of all the descendant text nodes under this `last` element.  So your code shouldn't compile, because it's not possible to cast from `String` to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check xml file which is being parsed. There should be something like

> `<last>textdata</last>`

By calling `getTextContent()` you are accessing `textdata`, by calling `item(0)` you are getting first accessible tag with such name.

Answer (score 0):

[NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) is designed to store an ordered collection of [Nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html). As it has multiple items inside, by calling `item(0)` you get the first item (`Node`) from this collection (indexes start with zero). By calling [getTextContent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) you get the text content of this node and its descendants.